# SQL Transaction and external call deadlock

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

For some reason we have a code like this (inside a procedure), on SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
update foo set value = 'xxx' where id = 123
exec usp_analyzeFoo @id = 123
```

where usp_analyzefoo calls out a web service that connects to the database on its own and tries to update table `foo` by itself. The web service uses native code, connects to hardware
(so I didn't want to have this code running inside SQL server) etc, works something out and updates `foo`. But it's made from a different connection and outside the current transaction.

It has worked until somebody wrapped these calls in a transaction and now the `update` command locks the table `foo` and the web service (which connects through its own database connection) is blocked by this transaction and times out.

Is there a reasonable solution for this problem? Something along calling the web service after the current transaction is over, scheduling it several seconds later (it's not critical) or something similar?

Comment: Obvious question out of the way first - is the transaction being committed?

Comment: yes, but only after all of this would complete (which never happens, as the web service is blocked by the open transaction)

Comment: You can call a SQL Server Agent `Job` which will call the web service asynchronously (Which will then run even if the transaction was eventually rolled back).

Comment: @Justicator - Thanks for the tip, I'll investigate this possibility

Comment: @Justicator - turn it into an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0):

You can call that SP whit a job like Justicator commented or you can put that call in two separate transactions.

If you don't explicit wrap that in a transaction both operations ill be done in implicit transactions by itself.

```
update -- implicit tran
exec SP -- implicit tran
```

when you wrapped it you mean to do both operations in a atomic tran, that does not work due the SP is calling a third party WS and it trying to do another transaction.

```
begin tran
update
exec SP -- call a third party ill be blocked by that update cuz it's not committed yet
commit tran -- ill never reach this point since exec does not complete, its a deadlock baby
```

you can separate the transactions if you wish, they ill work like before that (bad) wrap.

```
begin tran
update
commit tran

begin tran
exec SP
commit tran
```